# Easy Probability Question (Independent Events)

Tags: probability

Suppose I have two doors. One of them has a probability of $1/9$ to contain X, the other has a probability of $2/3$ to contain X. Then, supposing I pick randomly one of the two doors, what is the probability that it contains X?

(If one contains X, the other can also contain X. They are independent but not mutually exclusive.)

I'm not sure what the solution is - is it just the average of the probabilities? I need this as a stepping stone in a larger argument. Thanks.

Comment: Are you equally likely to choose either door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $E$ be the event that the door you open contains $X$. Assuming that you must choose either door $1$ or door $2$, but not both:

$$
P(E) = P(E~|~\text{choose door } 1)P(\text{choose door} 1) + P(E~|~\text{choose door } 2)P(\text{choose door} 2)
$$

Comment: Yes, I thought this was it.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you that the solution is just the average of the probabilities. If they are independent but not mutually exclusive, then if one contains X, the other can too... so you can't just add the probabilities. The next simplest thing to do is average them, but as one knows, in all things probability this must be a weighted average! Also, notice that 2/3 +1/9 does not add up to 1, so you must weight them so that they do! Ok, so, what we have to do is multiply 1/9 by 3, so that it becomes 1/3. Now use the twisted sum rule, where you weight the first probability by 3 and the second one by 1! So the sum becomes 2+1/9 which is obviously greater than 1; we need to do some more work here. Have heard of "fictional" probability spaces? you might consider them here.